# Twitter Bootstrap nav collapse Hide on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I click on a menu item the menu does not close. I have already checked the imports of JS and CSS and seemingly everything is OK, is there something else I need to do to run the menu?

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar  navbar-default  navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#home" class="active scroll">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about" class="scroll">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services" class="scroll">Serviços</a></li>
                <li><a href="#testimonials" class="scroll">Opiniões</a></li>
                <li><a href="#gallery" class="scroll">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#news" class="scroll">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact" class="scroll">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[image]

Comment: I believe your `data-target` needs to match the ID of the navbar; you have it matching the class name.

Comment: @RobertC But this coinciding ( #myNavbar ) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for me works...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.navbar-collapse a').on('click', function(){
            $('.navbar-toggle').click();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar  navbar-default  navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#home" class="active scroll">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about" class="scroll">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services" class="scroll">Serviços</a></li>
                <li><a href="#testimonials" class="scroll">Opiniões</a></li>
                <li><a href="#gallery" class="scroll">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#news" class="scroll">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact" class="scroll">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: @PauloRoberto i create fiddle for you check

Comment: Now yes it worked , I had not put the JavaScript snippet on the page , thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain, but i think it may be dependant on jquery ui... some bootstrap features are. I can't help much further with current knowledge of the question...
I've been having a lot of trouble with imports too.. you can try checking on your browser debug console to be sure everything is being load, also.. on chrome: f12, tab sources.

I hope it has been helpful.

Comment: Pardon, I didn't see your reply... So, try searching for the indefined indexes errors, or missing files that were not loaded... most other js errors are just there for compatibility issues, or other general things not related. Try to pin down all the ones that can be related to your issue bud. If you may, post a coment with each error so i can check it for you ^^

Comment: OH SORRY, you fixed already ^^, indeed it was missing file! see how those can be tricky? keep checking on the dev console by pressing f12, it's extremely helpful to understand what is missing

Answer (score 1):

```
Try It, I think, it usefull.    

<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
     <div>
        <div class="navbar-header" >

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar_logistic" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" id="button_menu_toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
             <span class="icon-bar line_orange"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar line_orange"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar line_orange"></span>
         </button>
        </div>

        <div id="navbar_logistic" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav flot_none">
                 <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Home2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Home3</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Home4</a></li>


            </ul>
         </div>
        </div>
         </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

check this out

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<body>

<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar  navbar-default  navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#home" class="active scroll">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about" class="scroll">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services" class="scroll">Serviços</a></li>
                <li><a href="#testimonials" class="scroll">Opiniões</a></li>
                <li><a href="#gallery" class="scroll">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#news" class="scroll">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact" class="scroll">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
  
</body>
```

Comment: It did not work , after the click, the menu remains open hiding content

Comment: if you don't want to hide the content below navbar then you need to remove 'navbar-fixed-top' class from navbar like this https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/chrfzen5/1/